# Separate Source Control binding for project in Visual Studio with SourceSafe

Tags: visual-studio, visual-sourcesafe

I have added my solution to SourceSafe using Visual Studio.
Then in the SourceSafe client I have Shared(and branched) one of the project folders.
Now, back in Visual Studio, I want to change the source control location for that project to the branched source location.  But when I select Change Source Control, I can't select that one project in the list: no matter what project I select, all the projects in the solution show as selected, and if I try to change the location for that project, it complains that I'm trying to set the source control folder for the SOLUTION to an invalid folder.
What do I need to do to separate the source control down to project level such that source control folder mappings can be done on a project level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, it turns out I had to unbind my solution from source control.  Then use the Change Source Control dialog to bind each project of my solution individually.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create a blank solution, add just the one project to it. Add the solution to VSS (the project should already be there).

Then change the bindings for that project-solution combo. Save it and close solution.

Now open your original solution back up and check the bindings for your project.

Comment: No that didn't make any difference to the project binding in my original solution.  In the Change Source Control dialog, the Server Binding column for all projects show the Solution Folder.  I've got a feeling that I may need to Unbind from source control, then add each project individually to source control, and only then add the solution to source control? This would be a real schlepp though because I have 64 projects in my solution!